# A small bug in the super-mega-expando search box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search

After a first search, trying to change the text in the search box results in some unwanted behavior from the search box.

If you select the text with [ctrl]+[a], the text will be selected, then the mega-expando kicks in and will put the cursor after the text.

If you select some letters of the text and start writing, the same thing happens, so if you have written 'ernomy' and want to insert 'go' for 'ergonomy', the result will be 'ergnomyo' (just tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can't repro this in Chrome (current version)
2. Once you've searched you don't *need* to use the top search bar. Instead, use the BIG ASS SEARCH BOX(tm):

   [image]

Comment: Jeff, you're right on Chrome. But I've reproduced the behavior on Firefox 3.6.20 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: When I push [TAB] the focus moves to the small super mega expando search, not the big ass search :(

Comment: The focus could be put on the big ass search box(tm)

Comment: @gui I don't think this is a bug on Firefox 4+ either.

Comment: @GUI What are you doing using Firefox 3.6 when 6.0 is out?! ;-)

Comment: @Rahul, I have no idea. I must be doing a backup shortly and update Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rahul, outdated by 3 versions in 10 months, that's wow!

Comment: Updated to Ubuntu 11.04, Firefox 7. Four version numbers in 10-11 months, something is fishy... Ah, and no repro :-)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: repro. I searched kerberos on askubuntu, then edited to put 'cups kerberos' and ended up with ckerberosups... I keep forgetting about the BIGASS(tm).